# Can you sit on the street?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request

I have a picture with a couple sitting on a bench in the sidewalk. Can I say they're sitting *on the street*?

I know we can use this phrase to describe the locations of buildings relative to a steet. I googled the related pictures and pictures came up showing people sitting in an **alley**, people literally **in the steet** (maybe having suicidal thoughts) also people sitting on **curbs**. Is it an idiomatic expression that includes all these that is something like *near or on/in any types of roads or path*? If yes does it always go with *the* or *a* is also possible?

I also came across [this sense](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on-in-the-street) which made me alittle perplexed to jump into any kind of conclusion!

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101511/does-a-pedestrian-walk-in-the-road-or-on-the-road-both-are-correct-but-wh/101525#101525). The same advice on prepositions apply, in the main, to *street* and *road* alike.

Comment: @Robusto I read the answer and upvoted it because it gave me some information about _walking in/along/up/down the road_ although it didn't particularly answer my question. So if I say _they're sitting in the street_ they want to draw attention to themselves? I'm not sure if it applies here.

Comment: If you say *they're sitting* in *the street* it's different from saying *they're sitting* on *the street*. The *in* version would imply some disruption of normal order, whereas *on* would imply a natural course of action. People "hang out" *on* the street, but there is fighting *in* the street., etc.

Comment: The couple is sitting on the _bench_; the bench could be said to be on (or _along_) the street.

Comment: @J.R. are you suggesting if there weren't a bench and they were sitting near the street (and on no furniture), then it would've been naturl to say _they are sitting on the street_ OR you mean it's not really common to describe people's location by using _on the street_?

Comment: @Yuri - No, without the bench, they would be sitting on the sidewalk, or sitting on the curb, or sitting on the ground. Although _on_ can be used to mean "adjacent to" or "alongside of" (as in, "That bakery sits on Main Street, right across from the deli") we wouldn't normally say that people are "sitting on the street" if they are really sitting on the side of the street. It's simply not idiomatic.

Comment: @J.R. I. _"It's simply not idiomatic"_ that was what I was looking for. These are some elusive parts of a language that makes it hard for a non-native speaker to grasp. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there's been a question asking about "on the street" versus "in the street".  You can certainly be walking *on* the street (in which case *street* includes the pedestrian walkway) or *in* the street (in which case *street* refers to the area for vehicular traffic). So you can be sitting on the street; it would be understood to mean "outside the buildings in the pedestrian walkway or on the home's front steps which abut that walkway".

> They sat outside on the street to see the parade.

People who are "living on the street" are homeless. They can be found on the pedestrian walkways of cities, often [living in makeshift shelters made from large cardboard boxes](https://www.google.com/search?q=homeless%20person%20cardboard%20box&num=20&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&imgil=A9HpfNVjgtW8GM%253A%253BCFNXe9oQHsaa_M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.theeoptimist.com%25252F2014%25252F01%25252Fmormons-utah-homelessness.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=A9HpfNVjgtW8GM%253A%252CCFNXe9oQHsaa_M%252C_&usg=__mYF0m2vqb8KCor0cweADEyO7dDo%3D&biw=1432&bih=886&dpr=0.9&ved=0ahUKEwjSmbaJqd_PAhWMPz4KHYTbAaoQyjcIKQ&ei=7XEDWJLvO4z_-AGEt4fQCg#imgrc=A9HpfNVjgtW8GM%3A).

Comment: +1 Thank you. I wasn't sure about people in the pedestrian walkway. BTW if you see someone sitting in an alley and you want to simply describe it, do you tend to say _on the street_ or _in the alley_?

Comment: Most native speakers would distinguish between **street** and **alley** when referring to the location as a location. But in fixed phrases like "living on the street" we wouldn't substitute and say "they are living on the alley". We could say "there's a homeless person living in the alley".